# IE - why it doesn't get changed?

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I've a got a: it works in FF but not in IE problem with my jQuery code, here the little snippet of code

```
jQuery(this).click(function()
{
    jQuery.post(href + '&rnd=' + Math.random(), function(data,status)
    {
        jQuery('.progress').show();

        if(status == 'success')
        {
            var d = jQuery('<div id="insertDiv" />').hide().append(data);
            var insert = jQuery(d).find('#contentframe').attr('id', 'insertFrame');
            jQuery('body #contentframe').after(insert).remove();
            jQuery('#insertFrame').attr('id','contentframe');
            var cf = jQuery('div.contentformular, div.update').clone().end().remove();

            jQuery('div.action').after(cf);
            jQuery('.progress').hide();
            //jQuery('html').after(data).remove();
        }
    })
});
```

As I mentioned, it works in FF but in IE only the `jQuery('body #contentframe')` is removed. Maybe someone has faced a similiar problem?

Cheers

Comment: why aren't you using the $ instead of JQuery ?

Comment: He's likely running in noConflict mode

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the whole problem, but you're missing a semi-colon on the end of the second to last line.